# Divergence of Curl for a vector space of dimension $n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

It is a fact that the divergence of curl, once the conditions of continuity $f (x, y,z)$ are satisfied, is equal to zero. However, all the demonstrations I found focus on three-dimensional space and use a lot of algebra. Is there any way to generalize the result to dimension $n$ more succinctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curl is defined as an operation on 3-dimensional vector fields.

In three dimensions the algebra is not difficult at all.

$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times F) = 0$

Which is just an identity of linear algebra.

To generalize to higher dimensional spaces we need a more abstract tool.  We get into the world of differential m-forms and exterior derivatives.  For an explanation of these, you will need to do your own research.  Michael Penn has a series of lectures on Youtube you might want to check out.  But the algebra of these operators becomes surprisingly simple.

On the left are the definitions in standard vector calculus.  On the right are the equivalent expressions in notation of exterior derivatives and Hodge operators.

$d$ is the exterior derivative.
$\omega_F$ expresses the Vector valued function $F$ as a differential form.
$\star$ is the Hodge operator.

Gradient:
$\nabla F \sim df$

Curl:
$\nabla \times F = \star d\omega_F$

Divergence:
$\nabla \cdot F = \star d\star \omega_F$

The algebra of these forms when you have $\star\star$ the stars cancel.  And $dd=0$ always

Curl of the gradient of a function, $\nabla \times (\nabla F)$

$\star dd F = 0$

and the Gradient of the curl of a function $\nabla\cdot (\nabla \times F)$

$\star d\star \star d \omega_F = \star dd \omega_F = 0$

Answer (score 2):

It's not a lot of algebra, really. It's just equality of mixed second-order partial derivatives. To generalize to more dimensions, you need to realize there is no curl, although there is divergence. But the machinery you need is differential forms and the exterior derivative $d$. $d\circ d = 0$ is the general version of $\text{div curl}\,\vec F = 0$ and $\text{curl}\,\nabla f = \vec 0$.

Ultimately, in $\Bbb R^3$ you can identify a vector field with *either* a $1$-form (and then $d$ becomes curl) *or* a $2$-form (and then $d$ becomes div). In $n$ dimensions, you similarly have the identification of a vector field with either a $1$-form or an $(n-1)$-form. For $1<k<n-1$, there is no interpretation of a $k$-form as representing a vector field.